# Lost data on dropped TCP connection

Tags: c#, tcpclient

The scenario is that I'm transmitting data from one machine to another via TCP on my home network.  The sender instantiates a `TCPClient` and writes data to the `NetworkStream`returned by `GetStream()`.  My understanding is that data in the `NetworkStream` is eventually sent to the buffer on the NIC and transmitted over the physical media.

However, if the connection is interrupted, the data in the `MemoryStream` and the data in the NICs buffer will be lost, but in my application, the data was written to the stream, and I could naively assume that the data was sent to the listening socket, but that's obviously not the case.  Once the connection is reestablished, the application would resume sending data where, to the best of its knowledge, the transmission was interrupted, but this does not take into account the data lost in the NIC's buffer and `MemoryStream` object.

Is there any way around this problem short of writing my own application-layer protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose data written to the socket would be guaranteed to arrive. This would mean that the TCP stack would have to wait *after every packet* for confirmation.

Clearly, this is not how it works.

TCP does not guarantee arrival except when you have successfully closed the connection. Only then you know everything was received.

You probably need to establish a resume protocol in the application layer. Ask the other side how far you got in the first connection.

A lot of discussion in the comments leads me to the following clarification: If the connection gets interrupted, the sender can not reliably know how many bytes were received by the other side. He will reliably know *that* not everything was received but not *what* was received.

Comment: Hmmm, I might as well just use UDP if I'm writing an application-level protocol.  Very good answer and good insights--thanks.

Comment: This answer is wrong - "TCP does not guarantee arrival except when you have successfully closed the connection. Only then you know everything was received.", this does not make any sense. Closing a connection changes nothing when it comes to TCP. If the data is flushed, it will be retried until successfully ACKnowledged by the other end. TCP certainly guarantees arrival of packets, but the processing/acting upon those packets is down to the application.

Comment: "If the data is flushed, it will be retried until successfully ACKnowledged by the other end." This is not true. What if the link is permanently down? Then the app thinks the data has arrived while it really hasn't. Tell me how you would ensure that data really does arrive, or that a reliable error appears at just the position in the stream where data was not received. You will not find an answer.; Even if Flush did guarantee delivery, delivery in all other places where flush is not called would not be guaranteed. If you write 1000 bytes, 900 might arrive, 100 might not. How would you tell?

Comment: It *is* true. The app would never think that a packet has been received that hasn't, the stream would fail and an exception would be thrown. What your first sentence says is wrong, it does wait after every packet for confirmation, and if it doesn't get it, it will retry. This isn't a synchronous process, other packets can be sent out of order, they just won't be *received* out of order (handled again by the link layer, it will resequence the data before passing up the stack).

Comment: If you write 1000 bytes, you will receive 1000 bytes, **or an exception will be thrown**.

Comment: No, if you write 1000 bytes the other side will receive the first [1..1000] bytes. Then, an exception will be thrown. But you don't know how many were received. Remember, TCP is not message oriented. Writing 1000 bytes does not magically convert them to an indivisible packet. You argue with packets but there **are no packets in TCP**.

Comment: I think we're discussing different points here. I'm talking about guaranteed delivery at a protocol level, you're talking at the application level. If you're using TCP for individual messages, then you would be framing your messages and if a full message frame wasn't received in its entirety the link would likely be severed, resulting in a failure notification at the client side. As stated in my answer, implementing your own ACK would probably be the best solution to ensure application-level delivery. *(and there are packets in TCP, just not at application level as it's represented as stream)*

Comment: My main point is that the sender cannot ever know how many bytes were received in case it detects a connection failure. There's just no way to know where to resume according to TCP's guarantees.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but flush doesn't actually do anything on a MemoryStream according to the MSDN docs.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flush.aspx  Also, if flush did, in fact, write data to the underlying device, that's still no guarantee that the data was sent :/  That's the point I was trying to make in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. One way would probably be to manually flush the data down the pipe on your `NetworkStream` after each batch of data written.

Whilst this may be seen as a performance sticking point, depending on your type of application, it will be the most fault-tolerant way to do it. By manually calling `.Flush()`, you're going to know whether the data was successfully sent down the pipe or not.

If you're doing this in batches from your `MemoryStream` into the `NetworkStream`, you can store the 'last written bytes', and be able to put them back into your `MemoryStream`, ready to be re-attempted when the connection is re-established.

Another option would be to implement your own protocol, upon connection, immediately send to the client how many bytes the server has received to date (ie. since the last connection). When you have this information, you can clear out the first X bytes of your `MemoryStream` (the ones that have already been sent), and continue pushing down the rest of the data.

One final thing you could do, which may be the best way, is a combination of the two. Basically implement a send/acknowledge protocol. This means, you will send a chunk of data, and wait for the server to send back an ACK/OK. When it does, you can be sure that the server has received this data, but if it doesn't, you can keep retrying until you get that ACK.

Comment: Flush does not guarantee delivery because it does not wait for confirmation.

Comment: The very nature of the TCP Protocol "guarantees delivery", as it's going to keep retrying to send the packet. If it's not sent after that call to Flush on the link layer, that error will bubble up to the application.

Comment: It does not guarantee delivery (how could that be possible in the face of failing networks?!). The app will be notified but at an arbitrary point, not at the point where data was still received by the other side. If you disagree, please tell how it would be possible to implement this.